# How to initialize an integer from a file

Tags: java, file

so i am writing a program and i am having trouble in trying to use initialize or declare a integer from a file in order to use it in the program. this is what the program looks like:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class WebberProject1
{
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip.txt"));
  String fileName = "portlandvip.txt";

while (scanner.hasNext())
{
 String firstName = scanner.next();
 String lastName = scanner.next();

  System.out.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName);            
   scanner.nextLine();  
}       
    try {
        File file = new File(fileName);

        String a,b,c,d;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            a = scanner.next();
            b = scanner.next();
            c = scanner.next();
            d = scanner.next();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(c);
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
 }
 }
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.io.*;


public class WebberProject1
{
```

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
  {

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("portlandvip.txt"));


while (scanner.hasNext())
{
String firstName = scanner.next();
String lastName = scanner.next();

System.out.println(" " + firstName + " " + lastName);            
scanner.nextLine();  
}       
    try {
        File file = new File("portland.txt");

        String a,b,c,d;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            a = scanner.next();
            b = scanner.next();
            c = scanner.next();
            d = scanner.next();
            int num = Integer.parseInt(c);
            System.out.println(num);
        }
        scanner.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    }
}
```

This is the file i am using.

Loras Tyrell 5 Club

Margaery Tyrell 8 Box

Roslin Frey 2 Box

Sansa Stark 2 Club

Jon Snow 5 Club

Edmure Tully 3 Box

Joffrey Baratheon 20 Court

Stannis Baratheon 4 Club

Jaime Lannister 2 Box

Cersei Lannister 1 Court

Beric Dondarrion 8 Court

Balon Greyjoy 16 Box

Olenna Tyrell 4 Court

Mace Tyrell 5 Box

Tyrion Lannister 2 Club

Sandor Clegane 2 Court

Gregor Clegane 6 Club

Samwell Tarly 3 Club

Petyr Baelish 6 Court

(i changed the spacing to make it look presentable)

What i am trying to do is to use the number after the last name in order to multiply that number with a certain number depending on the type of seat the data gives (club, court, etc). But, i cant figure out how to isolate the variable and the type of seat to use them for the program.

This is what the program outputs:

Loras Tyrell

Margaery Tyrell

Roslin Frey

Sansa Stark

Jon Snow

Edmure Tully

Joffrey Baratheon

Stannis Baratheon

Jaime Lannister

Cersei Lannister

Beric Dondarrion

Balon Greyjoy

Olenna Tyrell

Mace Tyrell

Tyrion Lannister

Sandor Clegane

Gregor Clegane

Samwell Tarly

Petyr Baelish

Answer (score 1):

Most convinient method I use for this problem is replace all letters except digits to blank.

```
String s="Tyrion Lannister 2 Club";
int i=Integer.parseInt(s.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

this will give you number inside `String` as I want to tell you it will work only for String like you have.

It will not convenient for `String` as `"Tyrion Lannister 2 Club and Number 44 "` it will give you `244`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class WebberProject1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "portlandvip.txtt";

        try {
            File file = new File(fileName);
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
            String a,b,c,d;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                a = scanner.next();
                b = scanner.next();
                c = scanner.next();
                d = scanner.next();
                int num = Integer.parseInt(c);
                System.out.println(num);
            }
            scanner.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but isn't there a different way to do it by using the scanner method?

Comment: @user3479350> Yes there is,I'll add it now.

Comment: im trying to use this for the program, but i keep on getting a bunch of errors

Comment: @user3479350> Just copy and paste the second part (as you want scanner), it works very fine for me and I tested it with your input.

Comment: @user3479350> Should I mention that `fileName` is defined   String fileName = "portlandvip.txt"; ?

Comment: i am really confused in how it is supposed to look like in this program.

Comment: i keep getting this error:  Unreachable catch block for java.io.IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Comment: it also tells me that i have to remove the ... in {...}

Comment: @user3479350> please replace your new code with your new edits with the current code on this page so as to I can see it, then I can understand what's your new problem?

Comment: i replaced the code i put on the page originally, is that what you wanted me to do? I'm new to the site, so i wasn't entirely sure if that's what you wanted me to do

Comment: @user3479350> I told you to replace my code with yours :)

Comment: ok, i used ur last edited answer, but now i am trying to use the part of my original program that printed the first and last name, and i am getting errors. I will edit my original post again to show what i turned it into so you can see the problem.

Comment: the first error i get is Error: Duplicate local variable scanner on line 24, but if i remove line 24 i get this error: Unreachable catch block for java.io.IOException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body on line 35. And no i have no idea what up-vote is.